# USB headset with good headphone quality and comfort?

Tags: usb, headset, audio-quality

I am on a headset for work several hours each day. I also listen to music extensively at work.

I currently listen to Sennheiser HD 380  headphones. My headset is pretty low quality comparatively.

What I would like is a good quality headset which has comparable sound quality and comfort.

My criteria:

- Sound quality comparable to my current Sennheiser headphones
- Preferably over-ear entirely (for ambient noise reduction)
- USB connection (acceptable to have 3.5mm audio input, too)

Comment: What price point are you looking at?

Comment: @NickWinans I didn't put a price range because I don't know my price range. My sennheiser were $150, so definitely less than them, but I don't have a very specific range.

Answer (score 8):

I recently bought the [Logitech G930](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g930-7-1-wireless-gaming-headset) ($100) headset for gaming and music and I can honestly say it's the best headset I've ever used.

- Circumaural and fits to ear shape (it isn't circular like most headsets — something that causes a lot of discomfort after an hour or two of wearing it)
- Dolby 7.1 surround sound that sounds almost just as good as sitting in a room surrounded by a 7.1 setup
- USB connection<sup>1</sup>
- Programmable keys  and volume directly on the headset that can be set to do anything you could ever want (to interact with Windows further than is allowed, see [this SU post](https://superuser.com/a/437959/447245))
- Extremely comfortable ear pads and headband — the headband is a semi-memory foam and the ear pads are just foam
- Mic that folds up and down — auto-mutes when folded up (one of the best features IMO)
- The companion Logitech software lets you adjust individual EQ frequencies, channel volumes, and talkback volume
- And of course an excellent sound range: 20Hz-20KHz and 30 Ohms

<sup>1</sup> The G930 has a base that connects to the PC via USB, and to charge the headset, a micro USB comes out of the base (a decent length). For the headset to work, a USB wireless receiver can be plugged into the top of the base or directly into the computer. It's a strange setup but it works. Check pictures for more detail.

The connection thing is greatly outweighed by the good features of this headset. You won't notice it after you set it up.

Comment: Just curious, have you used the [G430](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g430-7-1-surround-sound-gaming-headset)? I'm extremely pleased with mine and was just wondering what the difference was between the two. The 430 doesn't have the keys on the headset, but everything else you list sounds similar to the 430.

Comment: @Andy The G930's volume and mute are on the headset instead of inline, the ear pads are covered by pleather instead of a mesh (both are equally great though), it's wireless, and the mic mutes when folded up (I'm pretty sure this is only the G930, correct me if I'm wrong). So not a ton of differences. Mainly just for people who prefer wireless.

Comment: The 430 does not automatically mute when the mic is folded up. That is a feature I never knew I wanted, until now.

Comment: @Andy It's pretty awesome. I use it all the time along with the mute button. Having all the buttons and volume right there is a big improvement from having to fish around for the controls on the wire.

Comment: I have this one as well. The fold-up mute in combination with the programmable keys that are very easy to change is a huge convenience, I was _not_ expecting the sound quality to be so great. I love classical music, and these bring _close_ to the same depth as my much more expensive [brand redacted] pair with a preamp. They're a nice set to have for everyday use when you _aren't_ trying to hear that precise moment when the pick squeaks a tiny bit hitting the guitar strings. Also, range is actually better than advertised.

Comment: I would also recommend the [G35](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826104281&ignorebbr=1&cm_re=g35-_-26-104-281-_-Product) (the wired version of these). It has a 10 ft durable cable. The only downside is that the thin cover on the ear pieces is peeling off. It is like 3-4 years old tho.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to recommend the baby brother of Adam's [answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/292/57): the [Logitech G430](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g430-7-1-surround-sound-gaming-headset).

[image: Logitech G430]

Regular price is around $75.

- It fits over the entire ear (and isn't circular). I can wear it for hours at a time with no discomfort.
- 7.1 surround sound. It works very well in both games and movies.
- Noise canceling microphone. Team mates in games mentioned that the clarity is very good (and were appreciative when I started using this headset compared to my cheap previous one).
- The ear cups fold flat, so you can lay it flat on a desk.
- USB connection with on cable controls for volume adjustment and ability to mute the microphone. It is a wired headset, but the cable 7.5 feet long. This length has been fine for me. The headset actually has 3.5mm connections that plug into the USB dongle, if you wish to go that route.
  [image: 3.5mm to USB dongle]

Finally, I got my set at QuakeCon 2014 and have nice orange padding vs. the blue that you get at retail.

[image: QuakeCon 2014 G430]

Answer (score 5):

You might consider just adding a microphone to your setup (i.e. "convert" your headphones to a headset), like [this lapel microphone from Zalman](http://amzn.com/B00029MTMQ). That's what I've bought to use with my Sennheiser HD558's to great effect, and it costs around $9.

[image: External Zalman lapel microphone]

You could also purchase a USB sound system, like [this Creative X-Fi external pre-amp and sound system](http://amzn.com/B004275EO4), which you can get for around $90.  I'm not an audiophile (though I enjoy good sound), and I don't think that's audiophile quality - but if you're into good sound without being an audiophile, that's probably a good setup.  The upside is, you don't have to change your current headphones and you will get a better sound than other systems, in my humble opinion.

[image: Creative X-Fi sound console]

Best of luck with your search, and have fun!

Comment: I've got an external amp as well I use with my headphones already, this looks like an interesting idea to just get a simple microphone! I never thought about doing it this way.

Comment: Yep.  I was looking around for a while to get a good quality headset to replace an old Creative set I had, and found some forums (forget if it was Head-Fi) where they mentioned it.  Then, I got some good headphones and voila! awesome "headset".  You may need a splitter if your audio jack is one of those in/out mic + headphones one (like I have on my laptop), FYI.  They're pretty easy to find online.

Answer (score 5):

I have a Logitech G930 headset, which I am quite happy with.

On the plus side:

- Good quality speakers
- Good quality microphone
- Good wireless range
- Microphone mute button on the headset
- Microphone automatically mutes when folded up
- Has a practical base with a long wire for charging with a connector of better quality than most other micro USB chargers.

On the negative side:

- If the microphone touches something the noise feeds back through the speakers. (Even if the microphone is muted.)
- If you temporarily move out of wireless range while microphone is muted it gets un-muted as you move back within range.
- You will hear an annoying noise if you stay just on the edge of wireless range.
- The microphone on my first G930 broke after about a year. (But I was happy enough with my experience that I did use the refund I got under the warranty to buy a new G930).

The speakers do cover the ears and keeps out most of the ambient noise as you are asking for. Keeping out ambient noise can be a plus or a minus depending on circumstances, for example you might want to be able to hear a phone or a door bell.

Comment: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/292/6 ?

Comment: @enderland That does mention the same headset, but it does not list all the advantages and disadvantages I consider relevant to mention about this headset.