# Bluetooth headset with USB/3.5mm connection

Tags: usb, audio, bluetooth, headset

I want a headset. I have similar requirements to [USB headset with good headphone quality and comfort?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/291/1):

- I want a Bluetooth headset (so no cords hanging off my head) but it should connect to my computer via USB or a 3.5mm jack. My current setup does this with a base that is used for charging the headset and connecting to the computer.
- It should be able to last several hours on a single charge
- Should be mildly comfortable, but I can get used to anything
- I don't care about hooking it up to a landline, etc. I just need to get audio to and from my Macbook
- Should have a decent microphone
- Should last a relatively long time (>3 years), ideally with a warranty

I have a budget of ~$200. What should I use?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you want a Bluetooth headset (so will connect wirelessly to multiple devices) that *also* has a 3.5 mil phone jack?

Comment: @ArtOfCode My current setup (which I'll probably post as an answer sometime) has a 'base' thing that is used for charging, with a USB port on the back. The headset connects to the base, the base connects to the computer.

Comment: Right-o. So are you looking for something like that, or a setup where the phones themselves have the wire and the wireless?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'd be fine with either, but the base setup has served me well. Haven't used any other style, so I'm open to anything.

Comment: I'd be inclined to recommend the same headset I did for the question you linked to. Not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using a [Plantronics Savi 700 Series](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113210909/http://www.plantronics.com:80/us/product/savi-700?skuId=sku5860022#fndtn-overview) for the past few years.

[image]
<sub>(source: [plantronics.com](https://www.plantronics.com/images/catalog/product/large/savi_w740.png))</sub>

It:

- **Is way over budget** at $400. I got this as a gift through a fortunate series of events. I'm definitely open to other recommendations of cheaper products.
- Connects to my MacBook through USB (the cord goes from the base to the laptop)
- The headset itself is wireless, and has range allowing me to walk around my neighborhood block with minor degradation of sound quality
- Comes with a box full of different ways to affix it to your head - right now I'm using a springy headphone-type holder.
- Has a pretty decent microphone, with decent response time
- Has all-day battery life, if you remember to charge it at night.

My only gripe with it is that sometimes, if I leave it connected for more than a few hours, it starts to 'echo' - slowly turning into a high-pitched whine. I have no idea what this is, but it's easily fixed by turning it off/on again with the buttons on the base.