# Bluetooth headphones that can be used with usb

Tags: usb, headphones

I am looking for headphones with decent audio quality like Bose QuietComfort, but because I talk occasionally I need good microphone quality, therefore I need to be able to use to headphones via usb (type c would be also ok). Could not find such, except some Jabras but the earpads are small for me. I am not sure if this stack website is the correct place, but I decided to ask here, as I might receive help from more competent people. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that USB is better than Bluetooth for microphone quality? USB and Bluetooth are both digital connections and they both support enough bandwidth/codecs for voice to be encoded nearly losslessly. It's more likely that the actual microphone is at fault for poor voice quality, and that there may be many bluetooth headsets with excellent microphones that would work for you.

Comment: "Why do you think that USB is better than Bluetooth for microphone quality?", because it is a fact, I've done research and everyone would agree that 3.5mm or usb is better than bluetooth for calling. USB is better than the analog 3.5mm though

Comment: Once again, the microphone is the ultimate determining factor of voice quality. Bluetooth and USB are both digital connections that provide excessive amounts of bandwidth for high quality audio streams. The reason many bluetooth headsets sound worse is that they have worse *microphones*. That does not mean bluetooth itself is the problem. Bluetooth headsets with *good* microphones do exist.

Comment: The bandwidth of the celluar phone call's codec (max 32 kbps) is lower than HFP and HSP codecs (max 64 kbps). The audio quality is *entirely* based on the attributes of the microphone and analog->digital conversion if you consider that your phone will downsample even a really good USB headset. Bluetooth is likely to use cheaper microphones, because they use less power. That doesn't mean *all* bluetooth headsets sound bad.

Comment: It is a skype call

Comment: [SILK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILK) goes to a max of 40kbps. Still less than the maximum potential of a HSP headset. If bluetooth *needed* to be higher bitrate they could have and would have implemented it that way.

Comment: Well you got theory, I got practice and the practice shows that a 3.5mm jack from same headset delivers better quality from same headset via bluetooth - TaoTronics for 50 Euros

Comment: For that headset, I would expect your phone to have a better ADC than the bluetooth IC in the headset. Once again, you **can** get better quality with bluetooth. I only brought this up to keep all possible suggestion options open for you. It doesn't seem *necessary* to give up on bluetooth for this reason alone.

Comment: Both headset and phone have BT 5.0

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1101560/390174

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105053/discussion-between-romen-and--).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bluetooth headset with USB/3.5mm connection](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/596/bluetooth-headset-with-usb-3-5mm-connection)

Comment: I found beoplay h9 to be suitable

Answer (score 2):

Plantronics UC Voyager

Plantronics BT600

Either one would suit your needs. Our entire customer service department uses these headsets for their calls.

Comment: Does mic work over usb?

Comment: Yes, but the USB cable is very short since they are meant to be used via Bluetooth, and the cable usually just for charging. You will want to get an extension cable.

Answer (score 1):

New angle: What if you kept your current headphones that you enjoy, and add a mic?

Antlion is well known in the "gaming community" for producing detachable "ModMics" for users that don't want to sacrifice sound quality at the expense of adding a mic. They can be purchased [directly from Antlion](https://antlionaudio.com/collections/microphones/products/modmic-usb), on [Amazon](https://amzn.to/32OXJha), or in some electronic retail stores such as [Micro Center](https://www.microcenter.com/).

Another option is to purchase a USB desktop mic that just sits on your desk, such as the [Blue Yeti Nano](https://amzn.to/3aw5Jqa). Although I'm sure you would prefer the mobility of the ModMic.